# qt opengl stl render error with normal vector

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I get triangle vertex data and Normal vector data from a stl file, but when I render it with code like this

```cpp
for(uint32_t i = 0 ;i < mVertexCnt - 9;){
    int z = i/9;
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glNormal3f(mNorm[3*z], mNorm[3*z+1], mNorm[3*z+2]);

    glVertex3f(mVertix[i]/100,mVertix[i+1]/100,mVertix[i+2]/100); //1
    glVertex3f(mVertix[i+3]/100,mVertix[i+4]/100,mVertix[i+5]/100); //1
    glVertex3f(mVertix[i+6]/100,mVertix[i+7]/100,mVertix[i+8]/100); //1
    i += 9;
    glEnd();
}
```

the result is like

[image]

I think it is because the because normal vector direction is opposite to light direction.

my question is does OpenGL can handle itself. Ignore this direction issue and show the right light in every direction.
anyone know about it?

The light setting is like this:

```cpp
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);

//灯光设置
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, white_light);   //散射光属性
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, white_light);  //镜面反射光
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, Light_Model_Ambient);  //环境光参数

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);   //开关:使用光
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);     //打开0#灯
```

Comment: 1. are you sure `mVertix[i]/100` is floating point division? 2. are you sure the STL stored normals are correct ? what happens if you compute your own normals (by cross product) ? why not use 3fv for both normals and vertexes ... the `/100` can be in ModelView matrix scale instead ... Also is your FOV and depth buffer compatible with the mesh details (no z fighting) ? ... if it flickers while rotating its most likely depth buffer issue

Answer (score 0):

When the light model should be applied to both sides of a polygon, then you have to enable  `GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE` (see [`glLightModel`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLightModel.xml)) By default `GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE` is 0.

```cpp
glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);
```

But note this does not cause that the best fitting direction normal vector is found magically. It just causes that the normal vector of back facing polygons is inverted. Whether a polygon (triangle) is back face, is determined by the [Winding order](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling#Winding_order)  of the vertices in the projection on the viewport. Whether clockwise or counterclockwise polygons are meant to be front facing, can be set by [`glFrontFace`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFrontFace.xhtml).